# How to create shortcodes in PHP with functions that have parameters

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I'm building an intranet where I want users to be able to email other groups of users. I've successfully created a function that returns a list of user emails depending on their meta data (which are passed as arguments).

But I need help creating shortcodes. For example, a shortcode that outputs a mailing-list of all the users that have blue as a favorite color (data from a user registration form).

I've tried the simple `add_shortcode('$tag , $func')` but since I need to pass arguments that doesn't work, that will just list ALL the user emails and not depending on their meta data.

Anyone that can help me?

PS. I've just started to code so please be nice to me :)

```
function get_user_by_meta_data ($meta_key, $meta_value) {

    $args = array(
        'meta_key'  => $meta_key,
        'meta_value'  => $meta_value
    );

    // The Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // The Results
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    $result = array();

    // User Loop
    foreach ( $users as $user ) {
        $result[] = $user->user_email;
    }

    return "<span>" . implode( ', ', $result ) . "</span>";

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can adapt that code so it works with a shortcode. Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Register the [mailing_list] shortcode.
 *
 * Usage: [mailing_list meta_key='color' meta_value='blue']
 *
 * @author @cabrerahector
 * @param array $atts Shortcode parameters
 * @return string
 */
function wp44162_mailing_list_shortcode( $atts ) {
    $args = shortcode_atts(array( 
        'meta_key' => '',
        'meta_value' => '',
    ), $atts );

    // The Query
    $user_query = new WP_User_Query( $args );

    // The Results
    $users = $user_query->get_results();
    $result = array();

    // We have some users that match the conditions
    if ( ! empty($users) ) {
        // User Loop
        foreach ( $users as $user ) {
            $result[] = $user->user_email;
        }

        //return "<span>" . implode( ', ', $result ) . "</span>";
        return "<a href=\"mailto:" . implode(',', $result) . "\">" . $args['meta_value'] . "</a>";
    }

    // No users that matched the criteria were found
    return 'No users found.';
}
add_shortcode( 'mailing_list', 'wp44162_mailing_list_shortcode');
```

---

**Update:**

If you want to query for multiple colors, then you'll need to store every color selected by the user separatedly (see [add_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) for more details). Doing so will allow you to do this:

```
$args = shortcode_atts(array( 
    'meta_key' => '',
    'meta_value' => '',
), $atts );

$query = array(
    array(
        'key'     => $args['meta_key'],
        'value'   => explode(',', $args['meta_value']), // array of colors
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
);

// The Query
$user_query = new WP_User_Query( $query );
```

Comment: Ok so I need your help again @cabrerahector :)

I changed the code as you suggested. Now I want to return a link that uses the meta_value as the link text. This is what I've come up with:

return "<a href=\"mailto:".implode(',', $result)."\">".$meta_value."</a>";

But the $meta_value variable doesn't work, it just outputs meta_value.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Hey @lindag., don't mention it. Glad I could help! So, you want to return a list of clickable email addresses?

Comment: I want to be able to insert a shortcode on a page like the one you had as an example: [mailing_list meta_key='color' meta_value='blue'] and I want the output to be a link that holds a list of email adresses and I want the link text to be the meta_value ("Blue" in this example). So the only thing that shows on the front end is a mailto-link that says Blue which contains all the emails for the users that have Blue as the meta_value.

Comment: You were close. `$meta_value` doesn't exist inside the function but you can access its value with `$args['meta_value']` (remember that values passed to the shortcode via parameters are stored in the `$args` array). See my updated answer, I also made a minor improvement there.

Comment: You are my hero!! So thankful for this as the newbie I am :p

Comment: Don't mention it. One day you'll find yourself helping someone else too, @lindag. :) Happy coding!

Comment: Ok last question @cabrerahector Everything works great except when I'm trying to pass values from checkboxes to the shortcode. For example: In the user registration form there are some checkboxes "Blue" "Red" "Green" "Yellow". The user checks one or several boxes. When I'm looking for the meta_key it looks like it is an array. The input also have a class, checked="checked". I tried this but it didn't work: [mailing_list meta_key='color' meta_value='blue, red'] So I guess I have two questions: How to put several values into the shortcode and how to deal with checkboxes?

Comment: Are you saying that when the user selects multiple colors they're all saved as an array in the database? Or are there multiple color meta values for each color per user? (A screenshot of the database table usermeta could help, I'm more of a visual kind of guy.)

Comment: So this is what the table looks like for the checkboxes: https://www.lindagester.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Skärmavbild-2019-04-04-kl.-18.50.52.png and this is what the dropdown table (which works) looks like: https://www.lindagester.se/wp-content/uploads/2019/04/Skärmavbild-2019-04-04-kl.-18.52.52.png
(I've used different values than blue, red etc. It's in Swedish :)

Comment: Not sure if WordPress can query values stored like that from the database (at least with the code you have.) Chances are you'll need to store each color separatedly (which means you'll need to change how you save colors as well). I'll run some tests and let you know.

Comment: Yep, you'll need to store each user selected color separatedly. If you check the documentation of  the [add_user_meta()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_user_meta) function, you'll notice that it allows you to repeat a meta (that's actually the default behavior). If you do so, then it is possible to query for users that have selected one or more colors. I just updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hi again! So I ended up changing the user registration form to TRUE/FALSE checkboxes that return either 0 or 1 as values. That worked great, except for one little problem: since the link text is set to `$args['meta_value']` the link text for those queries will be either 0 or 1. I'm using ACF for the checkboxes and in their documentation (https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/) it says that you can get the field label using `get_field_object('my_field');` Displaying the label instead of the meta_value would maybe solve the problem. But I don't success. Any ideas?

Comment: That function returns an associative array, so how about this: `return "<a href=\"mailto:" . implode(',', $result) . "\">" . get_field_object('my_field')['label'] . "</a>";`

Comment: But what do I put where it says `'my_field'`? I tried `get_field_object($args['meta_value'])` since I'd like it to be dynamically but that didn't work.

Comment: Try `get_field_object($args['meta_key'])['label']` (or, on a second though, you could just use `$args['meta_value']`?)